# vb.net sql date index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This code seems strange for me because it doesn't have arrays yet it says "`index was outside the bounds of the array`". Anyways, here's my code

```
 con.Open()
                    'sql problem
                    Try
                        sql ="SELECT trans_event FROM tbl_transdetail WHERE trans_fromdate = #2015-08-16#"
                        com = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
                        reader = com.ExecuteReader
                        If reader.HasRows Then
                            While reader.Read()
                                Dim ev = reader.GetString("trans_event")
                                Dim lo = reader.GetString("trans_location")
                                Dim frmd As Date = reader.GetString("trans_fromdate")
                                Dim frmt = reader.GetString("trans_fromtime")
                                Dim tod As Date = reader.GetString("trans_todate")
                                Dim tot = reader.GetString("trans_totime")
                                .Items.Add(New ListViewItem({ev, lo, frmd, frmt, tod, tot}))
                            End While
                        Else
                            Dim i = reader.FieldCount
                        End If
                        reader.Close()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                    End Try
```

where the error is shockingly on the sql statement..
any help will greatly appreciated... thanks...

Comment: the SQL string appears to SELECT one column, then you try to read 6 columns from the result

Comment: yeah i know,...even if it's " * " ... it's still the same error

Comment: you also have a date var and try to assign a string to it: `frmd As Date = reader.GetString(...`  Strings and dates are not the same thing